# In Modal Logic, if something is true, is it necessarily true? $P\implies\square P$

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, modal-logic

I'm new to modal logic and I am trying to understand it more intuitively.

If something is true, is it necessarilly true? I.e.
$$P\implies\square P$$

This seems intuitive but it is not an axiom. This is not a book problem but a question I am wondering myself.

Let's take S5, which contains within it the following as axiom or theorem:

**B** $P\implies\square\Diamond P$
**D** $\square P\implies\Diamond P$
**K** $\square (P\implies Q)\implies(\square P\implies \square Q)$
**T** $\square P\implies P$
**4** $\square P\implies\square\square P$
**5** $\Diamond P\implies\square\Diamond P$

Is it proveable that
$$P\implies\square P$$
?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Please add some context to your question such as what book you are reading where this appears. Alternatively, please include your attempt to prove or disprove $P \implies \square P$ and where you got stuck.

Comment: Isaac, do you know or have you heard of the [Kripke semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke_semantics) for modal logic? Have you tried using it to prove or disprove $P \implies \square P$. Have you tried producing a proof in some proof calculus?

Comment: Alternatively, instead of a proof attempt, you could include links to other questions [such as this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/399079/understanding-the-modal-necessitation-rule) that refer to necessitation (that is the name for the property $P \implies \square P$) and describe what parts of the answers don't make sense. Or you could read through a resource like [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/) and quote the part of it that does not make sense yet.

Comment: @GregNisbet Your last answer helped. I misunderstood the necessitation rule previously. It completely went over my head. Thank you.

Comment: How do I close the post now?

Comment: The last thing I wrote was intended to be a comment directing you to sources you could cite to provide context for this question, not to be an answer per se. I am glad you found it helpful, though. I have voted to close this question as a duplicate of the question I linked to.  You can vote to accept the duplicate assignment. You can also still edit this question and cite that question as context. In my judgment, this question is *not* an exact duplicate of the linked question, but is similar in spirit.